# How to convert CIE xy value to gray scale value

Tags: image-processing, color

Is there a way [CIE chromaticity coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#CIE_xy_chromaticity_diagram_and_the_CIE_xyY_color_space) to gray scale value (0 to 255)?

Any existing implementation in ImageJ, R or Python?
Or formula?

Here is the table taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_illuminant).

[image]

---

---

**Purpose Description**
To respond to Marcus's comment below.

I have two color images taken under certain light condition (say F10).
What I want to do is to `correct` those images at the gray scale level (0-255),
such that those two are directly comparable.

So I want to use the given x2,y2 CIE values for F10 as base to correct them.
That's why I want to have those x2,y2 as gray scale.

Please advice if you have better way to approach this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space

Comment: @Ben Thanks. But I didn't see the conversion formula. What I saw is `From CIELAB to CIEXYZ` (and vice versa) only.

Comment: @neversaint honestly, these are white points. The whole point of these is that they're not just a colorless tone between black and white. Converting them to grayscale removes all sense from stating a white point. Therefore, we can't give you a "correct" formula – as none exists for your use case. Why are you asking this? Maybe we can help you with that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks so much for your response. Please see my update to OP. I added purpose description at the bottom.

Comment: @neversaint cool, but then what you want still doesn't work: the values given are *chroma*, you want intensity! That's literally orthogonal to that, and it makes sense: the whitepoint tells you something about the "tint", not about the "brightness" of the light source. So, the info you want, an intensity, is simply not included. You'll have to measure the brightness of your light yourself.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Let's assume I can get and have that 'brightness' value. How can I CIE xy value to gray scale value?

Comment: @neversaint **not at all** greyscale gives you the intensity. The intensity is not encoded in chroma. the info in that table is *literally* *everything about a color point aside from intensity*. For the n-th time: the info you need is not in there. could you stop asking for it.

Comment: The brightness you measure *is* the greyscale value you can add to the x,y tuple to get an actual color point. If you convert that to greyscale, you just get the brightness you've measured. I'll try to illustrate with an analogy: The x,y in that table gives you the fundamental frequencies in a guitar chord, but it (intentionally, even!) doesn't specify the volume. You keep asking "how do I convert frequencies to volume" and I keep repeating that these are orthogonal things about a sound.